# Is there any Linux alternative for Rainmeter?

Tags: 12.04

Rainmeter is a popular software used to customise Windows desktop. Is there any Linux alternative for rainmeter to use in Ubuntu 12.04 ? The desktop in Ubuntu looks plain!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `conky` you can install it using `sudo apt-get install conky` and see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=5436679#post5437628

Answer (score 0):

Not a ready and very common thing but I started to developing an open source, cross-platform, Rainmeter Widget Manager Alternative.

It's called **Widgetci**.
It's running in my Ubuntu 16.04 and my Windows 10 perfectly now, but it is not ready for normal user.

If you have Qt5.9 and Qt-Creator, you can compile it and test it, hopefully there will be win & linux builds published in several days || weeks: https://github.com/eminfedar/widgetci/tree/dev-stable